# what is $X / \cong $ ?? where $\cong $ is given by

Tags: general-topology

what is $X /  \cong $ ?? Suppose $X = \mathbb{R}^2 $. and we define

$$ (x_1,y_1) \cong (x_2, y_2) \iff x_1 + y_1 =x_2 + y_2 $$

With this equivalence relation, we get that the partition is the trivial one since every point is congruent to itself and hence $X$ is partitioned trivially. So we get the same space for the quoetient space.

But if we define $$ (x_1,y_1) \cong (x_2, y_2) \iff x^2_1 + y^2_1 =x^2_2 + y^2_2 $$

then $X / \cong$ is half plane.

Are these correct? CAn someone give me some feedback. thanks

Comment: Every point must be congruent to itself in any equivalence relation! Note that the first partitioning is nontrivial: if $x\neq 0$, then $(x,0)\neq (0,x)$, but $(x,0)\cong (0,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Will Jagy's answer, notice that $(x,y)~(x',y')$ iff $\frac{y'-y}{x'-x}=-1$ (since $\frac{y'-y}{x'-x}=\frac{(c-x')-(c-x)}{x'-x}=-1$ , so that two points are equivalent iff they are on the same line with slope =-1 . You can choose, as a representative of each line, its point of intersection with the $x-$ axis, and get an equivalence ( a bijection) with $\mathbb R$

Similarly, for the second case, two points are equivalent if they are on the same circle centered at the origin. Choose, e.g., the intersection of each circle with the positive x-axis, and you get a bijection with {$x:x $ in $\mathbb R: x\geq 0$}

Answer (score 3):

The quotient for the first one is the real line, you might as well think of it as the line $y=x.$ The second one is a half line, you could think of it as $x \geq 0.$

Comment: @BabakS., hi there.